# Matlab different data in Variable Editor

Tags: matlab

I'm reading in some data in Matlab and my answer results are different to the results in the "Variable Editor" view.. For example:

Variable Editor:

128
128
128
128
128
128
128
128
127

Answer Console:

128
  128
  128
  128
  128
  128
  128
  128
  128

Any idea why? I'm developing something in C++ and I get the same output as the "Variable Editor" but, not the same value as the actual console output..

P.S. the matlab function:

```
function f = returnData(filename)
rawdata = wavread('FILE_NAME');
f = rawdata;
end
```

And then all I do is "run file" and the output is displayed on the console.
Thanks

Comment: What is the type of the data? Is it doubles, ints, chars?

Comment: Apologies, the data type is uint8

Comment: do you produce the vector in your mex file? looks like it might be a memory allocation problem.

Comment: @angainor Hey, i've updated my post with the function.. Hope this helps :)

Comment: You probably also used 'native' flag to read the file.

Comment: @angainor Yes, these are native values.. BUT it doesn't answer the fact why i get two different datasets.. Does the console 'round the values up/down? :S

Comment: The point is that you ask a question, but fail to mention all the things you do in your code. Specify everything you do with your data, otherwise it is a waste of our time. I have found the file you use in one of your previous posts (craigyes.wav). I have read it and displayed it in both the variable editor, and on the console. The results are the same.

Comment: @angainor Thank you for your reply... So why am I getting different results? Do you want a screen print.. I'm really confused